# Regular Expression to match 3 to 4 digits

Tags: regex, perl

I am learning regular expressions and I am trying find this string day1otlk_XXXX.gif
where the 4 X's will be 3 to 4 random digits. This is what I have so far am I close?

```
qr/day1otlk_\d++\.gif/i
```

Comment: If you specifically want 3 to 4 digits(not 2 or less, or 5 or more) use \d{3,4}.  \d++ will match any number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex should be `/day1otlk_(\d{3,4})\.gif/`, maybe `/i` for case-insensitivity. if it's in a string you might want `/\bday1otlk_(\d{4})\.gif\b/` instead for stuff like `"asdjklfhlday1otlk_5242.gifiasdytoi"`, which you probably don't want.

the `{3,4}` means that there need to be between three and four digits, and the parentheses to capture those four digits in \1 or $1.

(bonus un-asked-for answer: if you need exactly three or, say, five, you can't do that. `{3,5}` will get between three and five. you'd need `\d{3}\d{2}?` or something of the sort.)

Comment: For the bonus: `(\d{3}|\d{5})`.

Comment: that works too, yes. probably works better in pathological cases, too.

Comment: @Svante: Even better would be to optimize out the common part: `\d{3}(\d{2})?`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that there will be 3 or 4 digits with the following:

```
day1otlk_\d{3,4}\.gif
```

The `{}` is a [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) modifier.  It's a little more precise than `*` or `+`.  You can use it to specify an exact number of repetitions of the preceding pattern or a range of repetitions.

`a{m}` - exactly m a’s
`a{m,}` - at least m a’s
`a{m,n}` - at least m but at most n a’s

Answer (score 1):

Kinda close. You have the `\d` for digits.

Do you know what the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) for regular expressions is?

Answer (score 1):

Very close.  This should do it...

```
day1otlk_\d{3,4}\.gif
```

The braces `{}` allow you to specify a ranged number of repeated characters `{3,4}` or an exact number like `{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

You specify a range quantifier with curly braces:

```
qr/day1otlk_\d{3,4}\.gif/i
```